# At a loss on how to handle validation that varies depending on the View in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, razor, unobtrusive-validation

Ok, I'm at a bit of a loss on how to handle this and I'm looking for ideas on what direction to head with this.

I am developing an ASP.Net MVC 3 w/ Razor site that will handle registration for a group of schools. At the beginning of the registration process the user is asked which school they are registering for. What school they're registering for will determine what information is required (one school requires SSN while another doesn't, one requires a driver's license # while another doesn't, etc). I'm using LINQ to SQL and am using the Models generated by LINQ to SQL as my view models. I've used unobtrusive validation through attributes throughout the rest of the site so I would like to continue to do so if possible. So how do I make a model's property required depending on the school they're going to?

One route of solving this that I can think of is to have a view (or a series of views) for each school and, some how, make the validation depend on which view is being used, but I'm not sure how to do that with unobtrusive validation.

Or maybe use the same view for all schools but have a custom validator `<RequiredForSchools(requiredSchoolIDs as Integer())>` if i could figure out a way to get the SchoolID to the custom validator (both the javascript side of it and the server side).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how many variables are there?  can you condense it down to a few, or less than 10?  In that case, you can use view models for each, which with a small number of variations may be the easiest.  You choose your viewmodel based on school.

If there are too many variations, then you will probably have to write your own validation attributes that do the deciding.

Comment: It's around 20 variables. Hmm, I wonder if I can simply inherit the LINQ to SQL's model for each school and apply the Required attribute there as needed.

Comment: do you mean 20 total variations?  Or as in 20 different variables, meaning 20^20 variations?  If the latter, then i'd suggest creating a custom validation attribute that can do the validation for you.

Comment: It's only 5 schools or variations, so I'd only need 5 classes, each with 20 properties, although some of those properties are required universally (ie first name, last name, etc) so I could leave those out and put <Required()> in the parent class. Although deriving a LINQ to SQL class isn't very useful because the DataContext won't take it and casting from parent to child and vice versa doesn't work. Hmmm... If I switch to a repository pattern then I could, but that's a lot of work for my project. Also, regarding making my own validaation attributes, I still have get the schoolID in issue.

Comment: Well, if there are only 5 schools, i'd just create 5 different view models, with different validation attributes on each.  I don't really understand why it would be difficult to get the school id, it should be in your model and accessible during validation.